# Объясните зачем нужен массив temp в примере!

Tags: c++, массивы, консоль

Подскажите, зачем в приведенном примере инициализируется локальный массив char temp[80] ? Массив не используется, но и объяснений нет никаких, очень странно, в книге не было непонятных моментов до этого. Помогите плз!
П.С. Книга "С++.Для начинающих. Герберт Шилдт."

[image: С++.Для начинающих. Герберт Шилдт.]

Comment: Стандартная ситуация - автор в предыдущем (или еще более раннем) издании писал один текст, потом его правил, ну, и забыл вычистить... А переводчик/редактор не обратил внимания. Это только Кнут выписывает чеки за найденные у него ошибки :) Тут у Шилдта еще ерунда - так, вызывает легкое недоумение, но код работает. Если глянуть на errata к "Книге Дракона", там вообще было обнаружено при подготовке русского и французского переводов в сумме более 300 ошибок и опечаток... Что до C++ - то это вы еще не читали 1 русское издание "Основ программирования" Страуструпа :) Там страшный как раз перевод :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, массив там не "инициализируется", а *объявляется* (и, в данном случае, *определяется*). Никакой инициализации этого массива не делается.

Во-вторых, отвечая на ваш вопрос: низачем. Книги Герберта Шилдта известны довольно низким качеством изложения. Такие "хвосты" там - в порядке вещей.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, довольно сложно в терминах разобраться...

Comment: Вот здесь вы не правы. Книги этого человека, широко известны довольно высоким качеством, попробуйте почитайте на английском языке, а потом уже что то обсуждайте о качестве.

Comment: @ImZ: С точностью до наоборот. Книги Герберта Шилдта именно на *английском* языке известны своим низким качеством. Герберта Шилд - это что-то вроде притчи во языцех в С/С++ мире, когда речь заходит о неряшливо написанных и переполненных странными домыслами книгах. О "качестве" его книг говорится даже в его Wikipedia записи. К сожалению, уважаемой страницы accu.org с отзывами о книгах больше нет - там о нем много писали.

Comment: WayBackMachine сохранила в архивах хоть что-то: https://web.archive.org/web/20050325080500/http://www.accu.org:80/bookreviews/public/reviews/0au/s.htm

Comment: Я так полагаю вы знаток книг по С++, не могли бы пару авторов назвать, книги которых достойны для понимания новичка?

Comment: @Nikita: Трудно что-то рекомендовать, не зная, что вы уже читали, а что не читали. "TC++PL" Страуструпа - стандартная рекомендация. Далее - книги Герба Саттера. Мне как-то трудно рекомендовать книги, однако... В наше время всему учит интернет. Только не вляпайтесь в какую-нибудь напыщенную бесполезную чушь с "остроумными" картинками с каких нибудь сайтов, типа Хабрхабра. С английским как?

Comment: С английским 50 на 50, с помощью переводчика,но думаю книги читать смогу. Я пока что читал только лекции по основам программирования:D в университете, но вот там точно качество подачи ниже низшего, я в книге этой больше узнал чем за весь семестр

Comment: Интернету я особо не верю, на одном ресурсе написано что "это хорошо, а то плохо", а на другом наоборот, я этот микс из учений недолюбливаю, хочу что-то одно и качественное

Comment: @Nikita: Можно посоветовать попробовать понемножку научиться ориентироваться в стандарте языка, именно как в *справочном* материале (не надо пытаться читать его как книгу). Однако это - не для каждого. Но если пойдет, то будет весьма полезным.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду знать теперь, что учить\познавать:)Я как раз по справочникам и документациям написал на с# программу, вроде как для первого опыта хорошо(для меня), но тоже есть косяки, элементарные вещи упускаются под определённые задачи, вот ссылка на программу, если интересно https://github.com/BansheeDark/NKProject

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62829/discussion-between-nikita-and-ant).

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю что это временное хранилище введенных данных.

Comment: Так под этот массив не выделено памяти, как там может что-то хранится? М.б. это просто опечатка и не более того...

Comment: @Nikita Память то как раз выделена, 80 char'ов. И да, это скорее всего опечатка, раз нигде не используется.

Comment: Массив только инициализирован, память ему не выделена, но это исходя из книги

Comment: "Массив только инициализирован, память ему не выделена" - это, простите, какая-то белиберда.

Comment: Если действительно не используеться, мб автор написал на автомате)
Обычно такие переменные используються для временного хранения данных. Думаю дальше вы их еще встретите)

Comment: Ну вот как раз про это в книги еще не написано было, так много непонятного, особенно толкования терминов, но это скорее всего перевод хромой

Answer (score 0):

Переменная\Объект называют temp, tmp когда подразумевают как временное хранилище данных в каких то вычислениях, например перестановка значений двух переменных. Не заморачивайся особо над листингами в книгах, там часто бывает много ошибок неточностей, в основном это происходит при переводах. Может где то этот массив, будет использоваться ниже и ты уже поймешь его предназначение, как временное хранилище.

Comment: Этот массив не может "использоваться ниже". Вся его область видимости, от начала о конца, приведена выше.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать на будущее